# How to save the result to self in Python?

Tags: python

I'm have the following piece of code:

```
def merge(self, list2):
   from heapq import merge
   self = list(merge(self, list2))
   return self
```

My intention is to return the output of the merge to the self argument. The above code doen't work. Is it possible to do this or am I trying to do something stupid?

Thanks.

Edit:

This is part of this class:

```
class MyList(list):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        list.__init__(self, *args)
```

Here's how I call this:

```
list1 = MyList[0, 1, 2, 3]
list1.merge([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

I am trying to save the result to `list1` itself.

```
list1
[0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: But what is `self`? And how are you calling `merge`?

Comment: You dont "save to self". If you need to, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @user295338 can you post the rest of the code? It's harder for people to give you useful answers based on fragments!

Comment: I added the code for the class in which this method occurs..I'm trying to define a list, call the method merge for the already defined list and new one which is passed as a parm. The call looks like this: already_defined_list.merge([1,2,3,4])

Comment: Thanks for the response everyone...I will try to implement a separate copyfrom method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning to self doesn't make a lot of sense. You are changing the class type.

What you probably want is something like: self.copyfrom(list(merge(self, list2))

That being said and given python's flexibility you will likely be able to get that code to work, but it will be very confusing to use and maintain.

Comment: You want to copy the internals of the list into your class. What I'm suggesting is to add a method that does that explicitly and use it here.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't use a loop and the lists append class?

```
def merge(self, list2):
    for k in list2:
        self.append(k)

    return self
```